# How to check if difference between two dates is exactly in multiple of X number of months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two dates (`Date` object). I need to check if the difference between is exactly of multiples of X months (considering days and last days of the months).

For simplicity, let's assume that X will be 4 for this question.

The simplest logic that I want to achieve are the following points (Only except that FOUR_MONTHS doesn't work, because modulo seems to only work with integers). So, I'd like to know if there's any way (that I might have simply missed) to mimic the following:

```
(Date.parse('2017-01-15') - Date.parse('2016-09-15')) % (FOUR_MONTHS) == 0
(Date.parse('2017-01-15') - Date.parse('2016-09-14')) % (FOUR_MONTHS) != 0
(Date.parse('2017-01-15') - Date.parse('2016-05-15')) % (FOUR_MONTHS) == 0
(Date.parse('2017-01-31') - Date.parse('2016-09-30')) % (FOUR_MONTHS) == 0
(Date.parse('2016-11-30') - Date.parse('2016-07-31')) % (FOUR_MONTHS) == 0
(Date.parse('2016-11-30') - Date.parse('2016-07-30')) % (FOUR_MONTHS) == 0
```

At the moment, I can think of looping through each FOUR_MONTHS, but I am thinking that it won't be efficient, and that there might be a simpler way or that I might have just missed a very simple Ruby method.

P.S. I'm tagging this question with ruby-on-rails because `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` possibly has differences with implementation.

Comment: This question is tricky, because dates are tricky. You should show what you tried before expecting answerers to code something for you.

Comment: @EricDuminil, you are right. I'll update my answer in a few minutes to include a working ruby, that I think is inefficient because it loops

Comment: One of the reasons I am starting to dislike stackoverflow now because of downvotes even if legit. I intentionally did not write my sample answer because I am sure there is a better way as it is inefficient. Please be more open-minded everyone.

Comment: Who cares if it's inefficient? At least it would show you invested some time in solving the problem. It also makes it easier to understand what your problem is, and what you want to achieve. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @EricDuminil, yes I do show sample answers most of the times. But for this one, I intentionally didn't. And that does not necessarily warrant the question to be illegitimate. Stackoverflow does not require sample answers to be written. I know it "can" help. But, I believe that my case in points above already would explain it, and that such answer of mine might actually just became noise to the simplicity of the question.

Comment: I don't really understand how some more code would confuse the question. Anyway, you got your question answered in less than half an hour, maybe you should wait a bit before disliking stackoverflow ;)

Comment: @EricDuminil haha I love to answer questions, so maybe I'll just answer and won't ask questions anymore :) But thanks a lot really. I was stuck in that for 3 hours.

Comment: Showing effort is very important. That can be done by showing what was searched and explaining why those pages or books didn't help, or by showing the attempt to solve the problem. The minimal code necessary to duplicate a problem is essential if you're asking about a problem with your code. Down votes get abused, just as up votes, but they can signify lack of evidence of effort. Remember, SO is an online reference book, like an encyclopedia, and questions start new articles and creating a good article takes effort, but doing that generates up votes.

Comment: @theTinMan Just like to say first that I am an open-minded person. I enjoy thinking about everything. Having said that, my following points are of just my personal view, not intending to downplay nor contend your views. From what you have said, this is one of the reasons why I think I am not favouring Stackoverflow anymore. Precisely as you have said, the website is promoting or (perhaps inherently has) superficial rules: i.e. "there should be a sample answer", "show references", "downvote if question is very easy or seems too stupid relative to the person who read the question"...

Comment: @theTinMan (I've seen lots of questions get downvoted like this), where in essence I believe SO is a Q&A, in that at it's core, you answer question because you like to help, and not to conform too much to rules (surely there are questions that needed to be more understandable or revised), but requiring a sample answer just to prove you've worked on it is not on my books. And as you have said downvotes get abused just as up votes, but downvoting without a commenting / having conversation is toxic; sure they are free to do as they please, but it won't help having a healthy ...

Comment: @theTinMan discussion or debate that would otherwise be contemplated upon and a better resolution/perspective would have been made. And I know this is not a debate website, nor do I know any better how to run things here in SO. But I can suggest some one or two things that could help SO, but I think I'll write it in their "Help Center", and not here. Sorry for bringing these things up in this comment section instead.

Comment: [meta] is where these things are discussed and debated. The site is run by the users, who decided what sort of information is needed to make useful questions. If you feel that SO doesn't work how you want it to you can take it up there.

Comment: @theTinMan ohh, I see. Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine with Rails ([`end_of_month`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Date/Calculations/end_of_month) is needed) :

```
def month_id(date)
  date.month + date.year * 12
end

def same_day?(date1, date2)
  (last_day_of_month?(date1) && date2.day >= date1.day) ||
  (last_day_of_month?(date2) && date1.day >= date2.day) ||
  date1.day == date2.day
end

def last_day_of_month?(date)
  date == date.end_of_month
end

def separated_by_multiple_of_x_months?(date1, date2, x = 4)
  same_day?(date1, date2) && (month_id(date1) - month_id(date2)) % x == 0
end

separated_by_multiple_of_x_months?(Date.parse('2017-01-15'), Date.parse('2016-09-15'))
#=> true
separated_by_multiple_of_x_months?(Date.parse('2017-01-15'), Date.parse('2016-09-14'))
#=> false
separated_by_multiple_of_x_months?(Date.parse('2017-01-15'), Date.parse('2016-05-15'))
#=> true
separated_by_multiple_of_x_months?(Date.parse('2017-01-31'), Date.parse('2016-09-30'))
#=> true
separated_by_multiple_of_x_months?(Date.parse('2016-11-30'), Date.parse('2016-07-31'))
#=> true
separated_by_multiple_of_x_months?(Date.parse('2016-11-30'), Date.parse('2016-07-30'))
#=> true
```

Comment: I thought my points are already clear enough. But, to be accurate, I am following how Ruby add/subtracts months to date, i.e. if the first date's day is 31, and added by 1.month, then the resulting date / sum is the highest possible of that month (can be 31, 30 or 28 or even 29)

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks

Comment: There was a bug in `same_day?`. Updated

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like `(end_date - start_date % x * (30.days / 1.day)).to_i.zero?`

Comment: This doesnt satisfy all of my points above: where months are not always 30 days in between, or when last days of the months is taken consideration

Comment: Question is non-specific here. What x months is it? The last x months? The first x months of the year? The last x months preceding the start date, or the x months preceding the end date, or some date in between?

Comment: please read through my points. I've put up 6 case-scenarios. I hope I dont sound rude but my question does not care if it is the last x or first x months of the year. Because you are right that I can use "to_i" but I still need one more step if I use that way, because I still need to check the last days of the months

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario: To be very honest, you do sound a bit rude. You're very prompt in finding mistakes in people trying to help you. At the same time, you don't show that you invested any amount of time trying to find  a solution. Constructive criticism is perfectly fine, but you could try to apply it to your code first.

Comment: @EricDuminil, I believe I was just trying to be efficient. And please don't think I was rude. I know there's this barrier because you can't see my face when I try to explain it. But, I do take your constructive criticism very calmly. But thanks for helping. And forgive me if I seemed to approach very rudely.

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario : I was actually talking about your criticism towards other people. If 4 people aren't sure what you ask exactly, it probably means that your question could be a bit clearer. Anyway, please show us what you wrote, and everything should be fine.

Comment: @EricDuminil, and yes I did reply to them and made it clearer. This is the simplest and most concise way yet not too overbearing that I thought on how I could ask this question, but I had to balance the length of the question, as in a lot of times, we need to get straight to the point and be readable easily. But, this is a good experience. I'll try asking to be simple again next time, and change my ways if people here would not follow it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `to_i` you'll get the difference in days:

```
(Date.parse('2017-01-15') - Date.parse('2016-09-15')).to_i
```

Comment: Yes. But its not exactly the number of days in between but months in between that I want

Comment: If you assume a month has 30 days you can just do: days % 30 == 0 && days / 30

Comment: yes. i can do that. but it doesnt yet take into account "last days of the months"

Answer (score 0):

OK 2nd try. You could use the `months_ago` or `months_since` method of ActiveSupport:

Assuming date1 is smaller than date2:

```
def months_apart?(date1, date2, num_of_months)
  date2.months_ago(num_of_months) == date1
end
```

Comment: I thought about it too. But the OP is looking for a `multiple of X number of months`. It could be 4, it could be 8 and it could be -4.

Comment: @leifg thanks for the help, but Eric has answered it :)